# Meteor: How do I successfully display data from two or more mongo collections on one view or page?

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor, view

I have two mongo collections named "theCollection" and "StreamingCollection" representing two categories of data. I would like to display the two sets of data from the separate collections on my home page, in two corresponding templates called "red" and "blue" within a larger template "Home" as shown below.

Data is coming through in the log so the publish and subscribe are working fine, and when I change my helpers from template.red.helpers, to template.Home.helpers, the data displays, but only one collection.

How do I successfully display data from two or more collections on one page??

Below shows my home page which simply has a template "Home" and this template holds two #each lists for the different collections, red and blue, which in themselves are templates.

```
<template name="Home">

<section>
    <div>
      <ul>
      {{#each articles}}
        {{> red}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
     <div>
      <ul>
      {{#each articles}}
        {{> blue}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>

</section>
```

red and blue templates are like this

```
<template name="red">
      <li>
    <div><img src="{{thumbnail}}"></div>
      <div>{{title}}</div>
  </li>
</template>

  <template name="blue">
     <li>
        <div><img src="{{thumbnail}}"></div>
          <div>{{title}}</div>
  </li>
</template>
```

These are my helpers

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.red.helpers({
    articles: function () {
      return theCollection.find({}, {sort: {count:-1}, limit:1});
    }
  });

  Template.blue.helpers({
    articles: function () {
      return StreamingCollection.find({}, {sort: {count:-1}, limit:1});
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You have two `{{#each articles}}` in the `home` template but you have no `articles` helper for `home` as your helpers are defined on the inner templates. Simply change your html to:

```
<template name="Home">
<section>
  <div>
    {{> red}}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{> blue}}
  </div>   
</section>
</template>

<template name="red">
<ul>
  {{#each articles}}
    <li>
      <div><img src="{{thumbnail}}"></div>
      <div>{{title}}</div>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>

<template name="blue">
<ul>
  {{#each articles}}
    <li>
      <div><img src="{{thumbnail}}"></div>
      <div>{{title}}</div>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

It's a matter of taste and style as to what html goes in the sub-template vs. the master. You should think about your templates being reusable in multiple parent templates. With `{{#each }}` loops you typically want to consider the case of empty lists.

Comment: Yes!! thank you @MichelFloyd that solves my problem!